# xcode how to get NSString from NSURL

Tags: xcode, nsurl

How can i get nsstring from NSURL from this panel to use it with another action too?

```
arxeio = myPanel.URL.lastPathComponent;
```

Answer (score 3):

`myPanel.URL.lastPathComponent` is an `NSString`.

If you want the whole URL, use `[myPanel.URL absoluteString]`.

Comment: i use an NSSTring variable to copy this, but when panel closes at NSString variable there is nothing (null)

Comment: if i call arxeio or even an other NSString which i use to copy value of arxeio to an other action i get null, that is the problem outside of the panel arxeio is null (logic) but even the copy of value of arxeio is null (the variables are global)